# JSON string property with the value of "1" gets converted to false

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

Using Retrofit on Android, I have a JSON response with

```
{
    result: "1"
}
```

I have a Java class

```
public class TestClass {
    @SerializedName("result")
    private Boolean myResult;
}
```

But I get myResult == false when I HTTP GET the JSON above. Ideas?

Comment: "1" is a string. So it returns false.

Comment: You can write your own deserializer

Answer (score 2):

Wrong type. String can't be parsed to Boolean. Just change

```
private Boolean myResult;
```

to

```
private String myResult;
```

If you want to check its value whether it is 1 or not, try to create a method for that.

```
public boolean isMyResultOne() {
    return myResult.equals("1");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that won't do. Retrofit is meant to be type safe, I need it to be a boolean property

Comment: Updated my answer on how to achieve your result.